# Jobs.stackoverflow not importing codeplex pull requests that have been accepted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

On updating my CV by connecting to codeplex to import my open source contributions I find that the pull requests don't get recognised.

For example http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/alski/StyleCopHighDPI/contribution/6031 is not being shown on https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/employer/11123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CodePlex APIs (https://www.codeplex.com/site/developers) for contributions are limited to information on projects you own. There is no way to get information on contributions you made to projects owned by others.

**However**, the way in which open source work is referenced is changing for the Developer Story (currently in private beta). It is expected that you will be able to link to anything and will not be limited to what the open source hoster's API provides. Keep an eye on the Developer Story as it progresses; once it's available to all you should be able to show this work on your story.